# How to fix ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

After some modification, instead of message is not defined, it is receivedMessage.channel.bulkdelete(args[0].then (() => { 
ReferenceError: receivedmessage is not defined. I am not really sure myself what does that mean because im new to node.js and javascript. If there is any mistakes I made please tell me!

```py
client.on('message', (receivedMessage) => {
    if (receivedMessage.author == client.user) { // Prevent bot from responding to its own messages
        return
    }

    if (receivedMessage.content.startsWith("?")) {
        processCommand(receivedMessage)
    }
})

function processCommand(receivedMessage) {
    let fullCommand = receivedMessage.content.substr(1) // Remove the leading exclamation mark
    let splitCommand = fullCommand.split(" ") // Split the message up in to pieces for each space
    let primaryCommand = splitCommand[0] // The first word directly after the exclamation is the command
    let arguments = splitCommand.slice(1) // All other words are arguments/parameters/options for the command

    console.log("Command received: " + primaryCommand)
    console.log("Arguments: " + arguments) // There may not be any arguments

if (primaryCommand == "help") {
    helpCommand(arguments, receivedMessage)
} else if (primaryCommand == "multiply") {
    multiplyCommand(arguments, receivedMessage)
} else if(primaryCommand == "clear") {
    clearCommand(arguments, receivedMessage)
} else {
    receivedMessage.channel.send("I don't understand the command. Try `?help`, `?multiply` or '?clear'")
}

function helpCommand(arguments, receivedMessage) {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("It looks like you might need help with " + arguments + ".Try `!multiply 2 4 10` or `!multiply 5.2 7`")
    } else {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("I'm not sure what you need help with. Try `?help [topic]`")
    }
}

function multiplyCommand(arguments, receivedMessage) {
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("Not enough values to multiply. Try `!multiply 2 4 10` or `!multiply 5.2 7`")
        return
    }
    let product = 1 
    arguments.forEach((value) => {
        product = product * parseFloat(value)
    })
    receivedMessage.channel.send("The product of " + arguments + " multiplied together is: " + product.toString())
    }
}

function clearCommand (arguments, receivedMessage) {
    if (!recievedMessage.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) 
        return receivedmessage.reply("You have no permission to use this command.Sad."); 
    if (!args[0]) 
        return receivedMessage.channel.send("Please specify a number.")
}
        receivedmessage.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]).then(() => {
        receivedMessage.channel.send(`Cleared ${args[0]} messages.`).then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
    }
,)
```

Comment: I can't find the line you are talking about in the code you've posted? [mre] ...

Comment: Sorry Jonas Wilms this is the old one before I edited it now its the new one

Comment: (1) you call `.login(...)` multiple times. Why? (2) you do have pieces of code that already use `message`. Why don't you just do it that way?

Comment: In the line you've mentioned, there's no variable `message` in `scope` (neither global nor local)

Comment: The truth is im new to node.js and javascript i said that in the description but they edited it for me so im not really know what to make coding work but i do know what they mean. In summary i have a little knowledge about coding but i know what the code meant

Comment: So if there is anything i can do pls notify me, thx!

Comment: 1565986223 can you explain more about it because im new to node.js and javascript

Comment: Inside the function `processCommand` there's not `message` variable (also I'll assume there's no global variable given the error). I don't know what your `message` variable is supposed to hold but give your code you could try using the variable `receivedMessage`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `receivedMessasge` instead of `message`, as thats the name you choose in that function.

It kinda seems like you dont really have much experience and I would recommend you to read the offical discord.js guide: https://discordjs.guide . It will teach you how to write Discord Bots without needing to copy a lot of weired stuff into your Code!

Answer (score 0):

1) You have defined `receivedMessage` instead of `messsage`

2) The code for clear command is not in any function and it executes once, before any messages.

You need to use `receivedMessage` instead of `message` and insert the code in the `processCommand` function

```js
if (primaryCommand == "help") {
    helpCommand(arguments, receivedMessage)
} else if (primaryCommand == "multiply") {
    multiplyCommand(arguments, receivedMessage)
} else if(primaryCommand == "clear") {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("You have no permission to use this command.Sad."); 
    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Please specify a number.")
    message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]).then(() => {
        message.channel.send(`Cleared ${args[0]} messages.`).then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
    });
    // or create a function for this command
} else {
    receivedMessage.channel.send("I don't understand the command. Try `?help` or `?multiply`")
}
```

Comment: Thx for the advice!